# Как получить JSON

Tags: java, json

Я формирую запрос:

```
String response = "";
        try {
            Client client = Client.create(new DefaultClientConfig());
            client.setFollowRedirects(true);

            WebResource service = client.resource(path);

            ClientResponse clientResponse = service
                    .queryParams(queryParams)
                    .accept("application/json")
                    .get(ClientResponse.class);

                response = clientResponse.getEntity(String.class);
        } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
   log.debug(response.toString);
```

получаю вывод

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.8.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

если этот же запрос делаю в строке браузера, то получаю JSON строку

```
{"result":{...........}}
```

вот такие заголовки:

```
{X-Frame-Options=[SAMEORIGIN], Strict-Transport-Security=[max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains], Server=[nginx/1.14.0], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], Connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[184], Date=[Thu, 29 Aug 2019 14:39:25 GMT], Location=[https://...], Content-Type=[text/html]}
```

что мне нужно сделать с clientResponse чтоб получить JSON строку ?

Comment: Может, заголовки запроса указать такие же, как браузер указывает?

Comment: Покажите заголовки ответа

Comment: @AntonShchyrov внес в топик

Answer (score 0):

Код ошибки

> 301 Moved Permanently

говорит о том, что вас перенаправили на другую страницу. Если вы увидели это сообщение, значит у вас редиректы запрещены. Нужно разрешить их.

```
Client client = Client.create(new DefaultClientConfig());
client.setFollowRedirects(true);
WebResource service = client.resource(path);
```

Comment: Я внес правки в топик. Протестировал... все равно вижу все тот же вывод...

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

Нужно из ответа вытащить URL

> clientResponse.getLocation()

и сформировать запрос заново с новым URL.

Подсказку взял отсюда: [java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/)